# Vue: How to insert a component to HTML in script tag?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Context**: I want to develop a community site. The users can post comments. If that post contains a URL, I want to replace it with a clickable component.

**Reformulation of the problem**:

I have a string data and want to replace characters “https://…” in it with `<my-component url:=“https://…”></my-component>`.

```
<template>
  <div ref=“container”>
    <!—- I want to insert the following content here—>
    <!—-The link is <my-component url="https://example.com"></my-component>—->
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      text: "The link is https://example.com"
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.$refs.container.innerHTML = ?
    // I want to replace here.
  }
}
</script>
```

I can use replace function to search the target characters with regex and replace them with some characters, but don’t know how to replace with a component.

Comment: It's unclear what you ask about. Where do you want to replace it? Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you know which component will be rendered? Could you provide more context, like the received data, the component(s) which could be rendered, etc.?

Comment: would be safer to use something like [linkify](https://soapbox.github.io/linkifyjs/), else your need to use v-html somewhere along the line which will open you up to stored xss

Answer (score 0):

You would need to bind an url property on the view:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <my-component :url="url"></my-component>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import MyComponent from "./my/component/path/MyComponent";
export default {
  components: { MyComponent },
  data(){
    return {
      url: "https://example.com"
    }
  },
}
</script>
```